# Derivative and Jacobian determinant of solution of ODE

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $\Phi$ be the unique solution of 
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}\Phi(x,t) = f(\Phi(x,t),t) \quad t >0 \\
\Phi(x,0) = x \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^N
\end{cases}$$
where we have assumed $f$ smooth.

How do you prove that $\Phi(\cdot, t)$ is smooth and in particular that the following holds?

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt} \nabla \Phi(x,t) = \nabla_1 f(\Phi(x,t),t)\nabla \Phi(x,t) \quad t>0 \\
\nabla\Phi(x,0) = 1 \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^N
\end{cases}$$
and
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt} J \Phi(x,t) = \mathrm{div} f(\Phi(x,t),t)J \Phi(x,t) \quad t>0 \\
\nabla\Phi(x,0) = 1 \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^N
\end{cases}$$
where $Jf = det \nabla f$.

Comment: This is more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com. I would suggestion writing everything out in their components $\Phi = (\Phi_1, \dots, \Phi_N)$, $x = (x_1, \dots, x_N)$, etc., and using partial derivatives and the chain rule you learned in calculus. The only hard step is differentiating the determinant, but you should be able to find a reference for that.

Comment: @DeaneYang I wasn't able to find any reference for these results. I agree that they should be standard, but I'd like to see a detailed proof of them.

Comment: For example, L. Perko [Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387951164), pp. 80-84, or any other good textbook on ODEs.  I wholeheartedly agree that this is a question for MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smoothness of $\Phi$ usually is addressed in the textbooks on ODEs (some of them are discussed on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81221/graduate-ode-textbook) and on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175908/ode-book-recommendation) as well).

An application of the chain rule yields the equation for $\nabla \Phi$, as Deane Yang commented. The equation for $\det \nabla \Phi$ is also well-known, but I cannot immediately recall a book where its proof is presented. But the standard proof was already sketched by Deane Yang.

For any differentiable time-dependent matrix $A(t)$ by [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) $(\det A(t))' = \mathop{\mathrm{tr}} (\mathop{\mathrm{adj}(A(t)) \cdot A'(t)})$.
In particular, if $A'(t) = B(t) A(t)$ for some matrix $B$ then $$\det(A(t))' = \mathop{\mathrm{tr}} (\mathop{\mathrm{adj}(A(t)) \cdot B(t) \cdot A(t)}) = \mathop{\mathrm{tr}} (B(t) \cdot A(t) \cdot \mathop{\mathrm{adj}(A(t))}) 
= \det(B(t)) \det(A(t)),$$ where [a standard property of adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) was used in the second equality. It then remains to substitute $A_{ij}(t) = \nabla_j \Phi_i(x,t)$ and $B_{ik}(t) = \partial_k f_i(\Phi(x,t),t)$.

Comment: Thank you. A side question: $\nabla \Phi$ if $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$ really the $N \times N$ Jacobian matrix of $\Phi$, right?(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)

Comment: @Hiro Actually $\Phi \colon \mathbb R^{N+1} \to \mathbb R^N$ and $\nabla \Phi$ denotes the Jacobian matrix of the function $\Phi(\cdot, t)$ with respect to the spacial variables. Probably in your notation it would be more precise to write $\nabla_1 \Phi$ instead of $\nabla \Phi$.