# Asymptotics for solution of transport equation and characteristics

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, hyperbolic-pde

Consider the transport equation $$u_t(t,x) + v(t,x) \cdot \nabla u(t,x) = 0.$$
Suppose that the solution of the characteristic equation
$$\dot X(t) = v(t,X(t)) $$
decays to zero as $t \to \infty$. What happens to the solution $u$ of the PDE as $t \to \infty$? Does it also decay to zero or to the Dirac delta as the weak solution formula
$$\int_{\mathbb R^N} \phi u(t,x)dx = \int_{\mathbb R^N} \phi(X(t,x))u_0(x)dx \qquad \phi \in C^\infty_c$$
suggests?

Comment: V is invompressible if its divergence is 0 everywhere. Such flows cannot have sinks as required by your 2nd eq.

Comment: @PiyushGrover Thanks. Can you show why if $\mathrm{div} v \neq 0$ then the solution of the ODE cannot decay to zero?

Comment: I am saying the opposite, that is if div v=0, then ODE cannot decay to 0 for all initial conditions.. Just take tiny circle around origin and apply divergence thm. Since all traj. are going into that circle, the line integral will be non-zero, but the area integral is 0 if div.v=0.

Comment: @PiyushGrover This counterexample is not clear to me: where are you applying the divergence theorem? Let's start over: if div v = 0, is it possible to prove that $X(t) > c \ge 0$ for every $t>0$?

Comment: Take a 2D example with 0 divergence. $\dot{x}=x$,$\dot{y}=-y$. See what you get.

Comment: @PiyushGrover Ok, in this example the characteristic does not decay: $(e^t, e^{-t})$. How can you deduce in general the lower bound on $X$ from the bound on the divergence? Is it still true if the div is bounded instead of zero?

Comment: Divergence controls the rate of expansion/contraction of volumes (or Lebesgue measures), think about case where initial data is uniform small ball around origin. If div=0, this ball will deform but volume will be conserved (e.g. it will become ellipse in the case I mentioned above). If div>0, volume will grow. Hence, a neccesary condition for all traj. to go to 0 is div<0, but certainly it is not sufficient. E.g. $\dot{x}=x$, $\dot{y}=-2y$.

Comment: @PiyushGrover Thanks, but can you show a general estimate of the kind $X(t) >c \ge 0$ under this assumption div = 0?

Comment: see this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327863/role-of-the-divergence-of-the-vector-field-in-transport-equations-mass-concentr

Answer (score 1):

Let me change slightly your notations with the flow $\psi (t,y)$ defined by
$$
\dot \psi(t,y)=v(t, \psi(t,y)),\quad \psi(0,y)=y.
$$
The solution $u$ is constant along the integral curves of the vector field, i.e.
$$
u(t,\psi(t,y))=u(0, y).
$$
Using the inverse function theorem you can introduce $\phi(t,x)$ to be a first integral defined by
$$
x=\psi(t,y)\Longleftrightarrow y=\phi(t,x).
$$
It is possible locally and let us assume that we can do that globally. Then we have
$$
u(t,x)=u(t=0, \phi(t,x))=u_{0}(\phi(t,x)).
$$
Assuming for instance that the initial datum $u_{0}$ is compactly supported or decays at infinity, you will get decay for the solution $u$ whenever $\phi(t,x)$ goes to infinity when $t\rightarrow+\infty$.
The natural condition for decay of $u$ whenever the Cauchy datum
$u_{0}$
is say compactly supported is that the first integral (which is the inverse function of the flow) goes to infinity with $t$.

Comment: Thanks! I have some additional questions: 1. Does $\psi \to 0$ imply $\phi \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$? 2. What happens in general, for example for measure initial data? Do we have convergence to the Dirac delta?

Comment: @Zac Since $x=\psi(t,y)$ is equivalent to $y=\phi(t,x)$, we have $x=\psi(t,\phi(t,x))$. Assuming $x\not=0$ we must have that $\phi(t,x)$ goes to infinity, otherwise under a mild continuity assumption, $x=\psi (+\infty,0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you! What about the second question on the convergence to the Dirac delta in case of measure initial data?

Comment: @Zac Well, under some conditions of regularity and behavior at infinity, the solution of the transport equation is given via the first integral above with the formula $u=u_0(\phi(t,x))$, where $u_0$ is the Cauchy datum. To prove convergence to the Dirac mass at $x=0$, you take $u_0=\delta_0$ which is indeed well localized; I guess that the arguments sketched above show that $\phi(t,x)$ goes to infinity for $x\not=0$, so that $u=u_0(\phi(t,x))=0$, proving that the limit distribution is supported at 0.

Comment: It seems that the weak formulation implies that the limit distribution is a measure, thus proportional to the Dirac mass at 0.

Comment: But if you take the weak formulation of the solution $\int_{\mathbb R^N} \phi u(t,x)dx = \int_{\mathbb R^N} \phi(X(t,x))u_0(x)dx$, then as $\psi(t) \to 0$ you get the concentration to the Dirac delta (which is also more consistent with the conservation of mass)