# Jacobian and Jacobian matrix of solutions of ODE with Sobolev vector field

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Phi$ be the Lagrangian flow (defined as in page 6 of [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/JEDP_2004____A1_0.pdf)) of the ODE
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}\Phi(x,t) = f(\Phi(x,t),t) \quad t >0 \\
\Phi(x,0) = x \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^N
\end{cases}$$
where we have assumed $f \in L^1_tW^{1,p}_x \cap L^\infty$.

Does the following hold in a weak sense?

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt} \nabla \Phi(x,t) = \nabla_1 f(\Phi(x,t),t)\nabla \Phi(x,t) \quad t>0 \\
\nabla\Phi(x,0) = 1 \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^N
\end{cases}$$
and
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt} J \Phi(x,t) = \mathrm{div} f(\Phi(x,t),t)J \Phi(x,t) \quad t>0 \\
\nabla\Phi(x,0) = 1 \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^N
\end{cases}$$
where $Jf = \det \nabla f$.

---

In [Derivative and Jacobian determinant of solution of ODE](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327714/derivative-and-jacobian-determinant-of-solution-of-ode/327773?noredirect=1#comment818497_327773), the same question was asked assuming $f$ smooth.